# Возможно ли сейчас распространение приложения на iOS с MacOS на VirtualBox?

Tags: ios, macos, virtualbox

Я создал для заказчика приложение для Android с помощью Cordova. Встал вопрос о создании этого приложения для iOS. Для этого я хочу приобрести компьютер на базе процессора: Intel Core i5-9400F (сейчас у меня AMD) и iPhone. Установить  Windows и MacOS на VirtualBox.
Меня смущает то, что MacOS будет не официально куплен. Я не нашёл свежую информацию по этому вопросу. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, смогу ли я выложить в Apple магазин мобиьное приложение, созданное в MacOS на VirtualBox и имея iPhone 6s 128GB?

Answer (score 0):

Единственный способ избежать

> Меня смущает то, что MacOS будет не официально куплен.

это покупка техники Apple, так как другого официального способа нет.

По вопросу выложить - да, сможете. У некоторых возникают проблемы с недоступностью AppStore, но в основном решаются переустановкой с другой конфигурацией виртуальной машины (из слухов).

Наиболее оптимальный вариант, возможно, подобрать железо под так называемый hackintosh. По крайней мере, работать будет быстрее и лучше чем в виртуалке.

Ну а самый правильный - купить Mac.

Comment: Без мака разработка под iOs это мазахизм

Comment: @MikeMclaren, частично согласен. Но каждый сам для себя подбирает компромиссный вариант.